# Common characters/statements in obfuscated JavaScript

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I'm trying to compile a list of common characters and statements in obfuscated JavaScript. I'm using http://aw-snap.info/articles/js-examples.php for obfuscated JS examples, but I cannot distinguish whether or not common characters/statements are actually common within obfuscated JS. Any list/source that could be more helpful? Or is it not possible? Anyone know common characters/statements in JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

Obfuscating in Javascript is usually done by generating the code dynamically. While you find older examples which make extensive use of `chr(..)` or base64 or lots of string concatenations detection heuristics improved to flag this kind of code as potentially malicious so that the attacked improved their methods. Typical current examples [like this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93370/javascript-phishing-attack-sucker-do-i-need-to-be-worried)  are not easily distinguishable from non-malicious code.

The methods used in malicious code to decode the obfuscation are the same methods used heavily in non-malicious code, i.e. `innerHTML`, `document.write` etc. Also, Javascript provides lots of different ways to call functions like `eval`, among them constructing the function name from a string before calling it.

In summary: there are no characters and statements which are typical for modern obfuscated JavaScript but which you don't find anywhere else. Especially if you look at the output from minifiers which are often used to save bandwidth and improve load times, you will find more similarities between minified and obfuscated code than between minified and "normal" code.